# How to use node-youtube-dl driver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-dl

I use [youtube-dl node driver](https://github.com/fent/node-youtube-dl) to get information about videos on youtube, but I have trouble with ReferenceError - require is not defined (First line). I installed node-youtube-dl module on my laptop and the code is just taken from example in description. Is there anything else that I'm missing to do?

```js
var youtubedl = require('youtube-dl');
var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q7Vr3yQYWQ';

ytdl.getInfo(url, function(err, info) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('id:', info.id);
  console.log('title:', info.title);
  console.log('url:', info.url);
  console.log('thumbnail:', info.thumbnail);
  console.log('description:', info.description);
  console.log('filename:', info._filename);
  console.log('duration:', info.duration);
  console.log('format_id:', info.format_id);
});
```

Comment: Are you running this in a browser or from a terminal/command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require()` is a keyword in Node.js. It is used to import CommonJS modules like those in the npm registry. But it is not a keyword in your browser, where trying to use it will return a `ReferenceError` as you describe.

If you want to import npm modules using `require()` in your browser, you can try [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/). However, it is entirely possible (probable?) that `youtube-dl` is not compatible with browserify or webpack.

If you don't need to run it from a browser, you can put the code in a file (say, `myFile.js`) and run it from the command line with node:

```
node myFile.js
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample:

> var youtubedl = require('youtube-dl');

However later you call it:

> ytdl.getInfo(url, function(err, info)

just simply rename your require to ytdl, like this:

> var ytdl = require('youtube-dl');